# Is there a way to change the fieldname of tooltips in clustered maps using the PowerBI Visual?

Tags: powerbi, mapbox

The tooltips using the clustered map only show the method of aggregation, e.g "Sum":

[image: tooltips using the clustered map only show the method of aggregation]

Is there a way to have this tooltip say "sum of testvalue" instead? I have it set so that the circle layer shows up at a certain point of zoom and these have better tooltips - but it would be nice to have detailed tooltips on the clusters too

Answer (score 0):

For now, it only takes "Measure Name"

You may create another measure and you can name it whatever you wish

[[image: attached image1]